# Does task queue truly run tasks in parallel?

Tags: google-app-engine, scalability, task-queue

We have an application that takes some input from a user and makes ~50 RPC calls. Each call takes around 4-5 minutes.

In the backend we are using a push queue and enqueuing each of these 50 calls as tasks. This is our queue spec:

```
queue:
- name: some-name
  rate: 500/s
  bucket_size: 100
  max_concurrent_requests: 500
```

My understanding is that all 50 requests should be run in parallel, and thus all of them should be complete in 4-5 minutes. But what's actually happening is that only around ~15 of these requests are returning results, while the rest cross the 10 min limit and time out. Another thing to note is that this seems to work fine if we bring down the number of requests to < 10.

There's always the possibility that the requests that timed out did so because the RPC response actually took that long. But what I wanted to confirm is :

1. My understanding of the tasks running in parallel is correct.
2. Our queue config and the number of tasks we're enqueuing has nothing to do with these requests timing out.
   Are these correct ?

Comment: That depends on the `.yaml` config for the module serving that queue. What are the `threadsafe` and scaling configs? In other words: how many tasks can one instance execute in parallel and how many instances are running in parallel?

Comment: @DanCornilescu We have threadsafe set to true, but we haven't specified any scaling configs explicitly. I would assume that would result in basic scaling, and from the documentation it looks like basic scaling also provides on demand instances as and when required.

Comment: automatic_scaling is default. But spinning up instances may take a while, you queue config needs to be able to buffer the tasks until the instances start serving. Check if additional instances are spinned up as needed when the task peak occurs and check if the problem is still seen when instances are already running when the task peak occurs.

Comment: @DanCornilescu The instances do spin up, but may be not as quickly as we'd like them to. Do you think we should go for manual scaling and have 10-15 instances running all the time ?

Comment: @DanCornilescu What about using multiple task queues ?

Comment: Unless you have, let's say, 100 idle instances I would drastically reduce the bucket_size in order to give app engine a fighting chance to spin up instances. The way it is configured now you attempt to run 100 tasks on a single (or few) instance, which fails for most of the tasks because the existing instances can't handle the load. Once the a few tasks pull though the measured latency will cause app engine to spin up more instances. You should try to reduce the amount of parallel tasks that hit few instances. Pay attention to how app engine scales and you can do a lot more in parallel.

Comment: @Shan: not sure about the manual scaling - could be great if you know what you're doing. Otherwise I'd stick to defaults and let GAE do its best, picking a config value without properly understanding its implications can worsen performance.

Answer (score 0):

### (1) Parallel execution

Yes, tasks can be executed in parallel (up to 500 in your case), but in push queues, your app has no control in which *particular order* the tasks in a push queue are executed and no direct control *how many tasks are executed at once*. (Your app can control in which sequence tasks are added to a queue though, see the pattern in (2) below)

App Engine uses certain factors to decide how fast and which tasks are executed, especially the queue configuration and also the scaling configuration (e.g. in `app.yaml`). Since you pay for every first 15 minutes of an instance, it could get very expensive to really have 50 instances launched, then idling for 15 minutes before shutting them down (until the next request). In this regard, the mechanism that spawns new instances is a little smarter, whether it is HTTP requests by users or task queues.

### (2) Request time outs

Yes, it is very unlikely that the enqueuing has anything to do with these request time outs. Unless the time-outs are an unintentional side-effect of the wrong assumption that a particular task was executed before.

In order to avoid request time outs in general, it makes sense to split a task into multiple tasks. For example, if you have a task `do_foo` and those executions exceed the time outs frequently (or memory limits), you could instead have `do_foo` load off work to other tasks that will do the actual jobs.

For some migration tasks I use this pattern in a linear / sequential way. E.g. classmethod `do_foo` just queries entities of a certain kind (ordered by creation timestamp for example), maybe filtered, by page (e.g. 50 in transactions with ancestor). It does some writes to the entities first, and only at the very end after successful commit it creates a new transactional `do_foo` task with cursor parameter to the next page, eventually with a countdown of 1 sec to avoid transaction errors. The next execution of `do_foo` will continue with the next page (of course only after the task with the previous page completed).

Depending on the nature of the tasks, you could alternatively have each task fan out into multiple tasks per execution, e.g. `do_foo` triggers `do_bar`, `do_something` and `do_more`. Also note that up to five tasks can be created transactionally inside a transaction.